# LiteDB reference multiple/different collections in the same property

Tags: c#, .net, litedb

**tl;dr:** Is it possible to reference multiple, different, collections in the same property?

I have an interface:

```cs
public interface IItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

And 2 classes that implement it:

```cs
// Directory - collection = "directories"
public class Directory : IItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [BsonRef("files")]
    public List<IItem> Children { get; set; } = new List<IItem>();
}

// File - collection = "files"
public class File : IItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

The `[BsonRef("files")]` reference works fine, but Directory.Children can contain either directories or files, and the `BsonRef()` decorator only accepts one collection. I also tried the BsonMapper fluent API method.

Is this possible?  I could probably just put them in the same collection, but I'd rather keep them separate as I want to find the files by their ID.